# Spring + Hibernate: Save not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a pretty easy use case and for some reason I can't get a save method working. I'm calling the method below from another class. There's a Transactional annotation in order to always commit the transaction after the method.

```
@Transactional
public ApiKeys save(ApiKeys apiKey) {
    log.debug("Request to save ApiKeys : {}", apiKey);

    if(apiKey.getSecret() == null && apiKey.getId() != null)
    {
        ApiKeys apiKeyFromDb = findOne(apiKey.getId());
        apiKey.setSecret(apiKeyFromDb.getSecret());
        apiKey.setSalt(apiKeyFromDb.getSalt());
    }

    return apiKeysRepository.save(apiKey);
}
```

I haven't implemented the repository method, it's the one from CrudRepository.class:

```
/**
 * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
 * entity instance completely.
 * 
 * @param entity
 * @return the saved entity
 */
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

However, when I step through the class, it normally steps through the save method, but isn't doing anything (meaning: there's no update statement stated in the console, no error - I also wrapped it in a try-catch, but nothing happens.

Does anybody have a hint on what I'm doing wrong? Also, if you need more code, I'll be happy to provide more snippets.

Comment: `there's no update statement stated in the console` - are there any other statements? Are you sure logging the statements is turned on? Did you check the database? Kinda obvious questions, but who knows.

Comment: Legit questions. But unfortunately: Logging is turned on since I'm seeing other update/insert statements in the console. I checked the database but nothing changed.

Comment: Could be that class owner is not spring bean. How to you access the class/method? Is it autowired?

Comment: Unfortunately every affected class is decorated with an Service annotation. The dependency is injected with Autowired. Really no idea what could go wrong. I also set hibernate logging to DEBUG (in logback-spring.xml), but no log whatsoever...

Comment: Could you provide your repository code?

Comment: I haven't implemented that, it's the one from CrudRepository.class (I've added it in the original post)

Comment: The most probable explanation is that there is nothing to save, because you haven't changed the object since you loaded it in the transaction.

Comment: Have you enabled the spring data repositories via XML or with the `@EnableAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: Yes, I did. 
@JBNizet that sounds really stupid but that might be the solution. I thought I changed something, but the value in the DB didn't get changed, and thus nothing needed to be saved... I will investigate it further but so far I think that was really the issue... Sorry for bothering and thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Could you please provide your repository class? I know its implementing crudRepo but if possible just provide it

Comment: Sure, I already provided it, please check my opening thread (I updated that)